# what is $tan^3$ in $\tan ^3 x - 1 + 1/\cos ^2 x - 3 \cot(\pi/2 - x) = 3$

Tags: trigonometry

$\tan ^3 x - 1 + 1/\cos ^2 x - 3 \cot(\pi/2 - x) = 3$

modify little bit : $\tan ^3 x + \tan^2 x - 3\tan x = 3$

$ \Rightarrow A^3 + A^2 - 3A = 3$

For $-1\leq A \leq 1$ we get $A = -1$ so $\tan^3x = A^3 = -1$

i am still not sure but is it true? thanks

Comment: No, $-1\le \tan x \le 1$ is not true, so other zeros of your polynomial $A^3+A^2-3A-3$ must also be considered.

Comment: @GEdgar why $-1 \leq \tan x \leq 1$ not true?

Comment: Note $\tan \pi/3 = \sqrt{3} > 1$, in fact $\tan x > 1$ for $\pi/4 < x < \pi/2$.  In some right triangles, the opposite side is longer than the adjacent side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decompose the polynomial, obtaining: $$(A+1)(A^2-3)$$
From here, you have: $\tan(x)=\pm\sqrt3 \lor \tan(x)=-1$ and so the solutions are:
$$x = 3\pi/4+k\pi \lor x = \pi/3+k\pi \lor x = 2\pi/3 +k\pi, k \in Z$$